# Facets removed when using contextual filter (category page)

Tags: taxonomy-terms, commerce, search

I have taxonomy terms, which are also enabled in the menu (besides the *all*). The *all* points to the default product search page (`/products`) for which i have configured the search API to show two facets (*category* and *location*). 
I am now trying to setup the `/product-category/%` page to also show a facet (for *location*). This view is also in the context of search (its type is "Product Display"). All seems to work as long as the contextual filter does not match

So when i type `/product-category/BOGUS` i get the facets, but when i do `/product-category/realthing` it does not show the facets (the whole sidebar first is not used)

I am finding it awkward that this proves to be so difficult. What i want is people to drill further down after having selected the *category* from the menu.

Comment: I do know that facets only appear when data is being returned to the page that matches. So if you use a product that doesn't have any facets associated with it, the facets shouldn't appear (at least last time I had this issue that was the case).

Comment: The products shown have values associated with the facets (plus i have set up the facets to show even when no matches exists). The whole facet blocks are not shown when using a matching contextual filter value. Should this just work according to you? Tx.

Comment: You could use Facet API Pretty Paths and not use the contextual search, then just add the facet block based on the path.

Comment: It turns out my URL are captured by the URL aliases and  when i enter `/product-category/realthing` it in fact goes to the taxonomy term page. When using the URL `/product-category/BOGUS` it went to my view. It is not working yet, but that explains the strange behaviour.

Comment: Ah, yep, that'd do it, hence why there aren't any facets showing up because it's not a search view.